# How to add Checkbox to every row of table to update/delete the row data from phpmyadmin in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

May i know where and how do i need to do. I want to add a checkbox in every row and when it checked, the button of update or delete will only effect to the checked row.
I am new in python and currently i'm doing this for my project gui, is that anyone can help or if any suggestion you're welcome. Thanks

Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import mysql.connector

win = Tk()
win.title("Admin Signup")
win.geometry("750x400+300+90")

frame1 = Frame(win)
frame1.pack(side = TOP, fill=X)

frame2 = Frame(win)
frame2.pack(side = TOP, fill=X)

frame3 = Frame(win)
frame3.pack(side = TOP, padx = 10, pady=15)

frame4 = Frame(win)
frame4.pack(side = TOP, padx = 10)

frame5 = Frame(win)
frame5.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10)

lbl_title = Label(frame1, text = "User List", font = ("BOLD 20"))
lbl_title.pack(side = TOP, anchor = "w", padx = 20, pady = 20)

btn_register = Button(frame2, text = "Register User")
btn_register.pack(side = TOP, anchor = "e", padx=20)

lbl01 = Label(frame3, text="Username", width=17, anchor="w", relief="raised")
lbl01.grid(row=0, column=0)

lbl02 = Label(frame3, text="Password", width=17, anchor="w", relief="raised")
lbl02.grid(row=0, column=1)

lbl03 = Label(frame3, text="Full Name", width=17, anchor="w", relief="raised")
lbl03.grid(row=0, column=2)

lbl04 = Label(frame3, text="Ic Number", width=17, anchor="w", relief="raised")
lbl04.grid(row=0, column=3)

lbl05 = Label(frame3, text="Staff Id", width=17, anchor="w", relief="raised")
lbl05.grid(row=0, column=4)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "username",
    password = "password",
    database = "adminacc"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM acc")
i = 0

for details in mycursor:
    for j in range(len(details)):
        e = Entry(frame4, width=17, relief=SUNKEN)
        e.grid(row=i, column=j)
        e.insert(END, details[j])
        e.config(state=DISABLED, disabledforeground="blue")
    i = i+1
    
btn_update = Button(frame5, text = "Update")
btn_update.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15)

btn_delete = Button(frame5, text = "Delete")
btn_delete.grid(row=0, column=1)

win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every row behaves the same, suggest to use a class to encapsulate the behavior:

```
class AccountInfo:
    def __init__(self, parent, details, row):
        self.entries = []
        # create entry box for each item in 'details'
        for col, item in enumerate(details):
            e = Entry(parent, width=17, relief=SUNKEN, disabledforeground='blue', bd=2)
            e.grid(row=row, column=col)
            e.insert(END, item)
            e.config(state=DISABLED)
            self.entries.append(e)
        # create the checkbutton to select/deselect current row
        self.var = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(parent, variable=self.var, command=self.state_changed).grid(row=row, column=col+1)

    def state_changed(self):
        state = NORMAL if self.selected else DISABLED
        # enable/disable entries except username
        for e in self.entries[1:]:
            e.config(state=state)

    @property
    def selected(self):
        return self.var.get()

    @property
    def values(self):
        return tuple(x.get() for x in self.entries)
```

Then using the class to create the required rows for each record retrieved from database:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM acc")

accounts = []  # used to store the rows (accounts)
for row, details in enumerate(mycursor):
    acc = AccountInfo(frame4, details, row)
    accounts.append(acc)
```

The saved accounts can then be used in the callbacks of <kbd>Update</kbd> and <kbd>Delete</kbd> buttons:

```
def update_accounts():
    for acc in accounts:
        if acc.selected:
            print(acc.values)
            # do whatever you want on this selected account

btn_update = Button(frame5, text="Update", command=update_accounts)
```

Same logic on <kbd>Delete</kbd> button.

Note that you can modify the `AccountInfo` class to add functionalities that suit what you need.